# Can't pass object of model in arguments of django custom template filter

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I created a custom filter in django template, but django has some constraints in passing  no. of arguments, it allows only one or two arguments for custom filter functions [Read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters). And, i want to pass two arguments to my custom filter one is `string` and second one is `object` of model class. But can't able to successfully accomplish this.

**index.html**

```
{% load has_permission_filter %}
{% for u in users %}
 <span class={{ user|has_location_perm:('user.view_user', u)}}>View</span>
{% endfor %}
```

In above template `user` is current logged user and `users` is a list of instances of `User` model class.

**has_permission_filter.py**

```
def has_location_perm(user, args):
    perm_str, obj = args[0], args[1]
    // business logic
    if user.has_perm(perm_str) and business_logic_check(perm_str, obj):
        return 'allow'
    else:
        return 'not-allow'
```

So, I want a some sort of solution which helps me in passing `object` in filter function from django template.

Comment: Why do you need to pass in `user`, Are you not just checking if user `u` has the permission?

Comment: To me your html looks somewhat confusing. Where does `user` come from (in your span tag)?

Comment: @cezar i have edit question, please see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use multiple arguments with filters. You can with a [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) though.

Comment: If the argument was a template variable,simple tag function is passed the current value of the variable, not the variable itself. so how i can use variable `u` attributes in my function.

Comment: The simple tag will work fine. That sentence in the docs means that the tag will be passed the user `u`, not the string `'u'`. The simple tag takes care of fetching the value of `'u'` from the template context.

Comment: @sander-van-leeuwen thanks bro, this solution really works.